# Space and time complexity of lisp functions

Tags: algorithm, lisp, time-complexity, space-complexity

Here are two lisp's functions

```
(defun fact (x &optional (acc 1))
  (if (zerop x) acc
      (fatt (- 1 x) (* x acc))))

(defun fatt (x)
  (if (zerop x) 1
      (* x (fatt (- x 1)))))
```

How can I find space and time complexity of this functions?

Comment: Most probably there are 2 typos in your code: you probably want to call `fact` and not `fatt` from `fact`, and I think you mixed the subtract parameter order, so the expression should read `(fact (- x 1) (* x acc))`.

Answer (score 1):

The (corrected version of) the first function

```
(defun fact (x &optional (acc 1))
  (if (zerop x) 
      acc
      (fact (- x 1) (* x acc))))
```

when called with `(fact N)`, has time complexity O(N) as the steps are the same for each recursive level, and there are N recursive calls. Space complexity depends on the compiler.

Every decent LISP compiler does tail-recursion optimization, so the recursive call of `fact` gets replaced with a "jump" to the beginning of the `fact` function with the parameters being replaced by the new ones. So you only have one set of variables `x` and `acc`, meaning O(1).

Of course, with a stupid compiler, you'll end up with N call stack frames, each having its own set of variables `x` and `acc`, meaning O(N).

The second function

```
(defun fatt (x)
  (if (zerop x) 
      1
      (* x (fatt (- x 1)))))
```

doesn't (typically - maybe there are some very clever compilers around...) allow for tail-recursion optimization, so, when called with `(fatt N)`, you end up with both time and space being O(N).

**Nitpicking**:

If you use large N values, the computation will no longer fit into the fixnum number range and use bignums instead, then violating the assumption that all recursive invocations execute the same steps. In fact, the execution time for things like multiplication and subtraction increase with the length of the numbers. For factorials that fit into the computer's memory, it'll probably be O(log(x)) instead of O(1) for every step. So for large numbers, we'll observe O(NlogN) instead of O(N).

Comment: In first function we have N recursive calls but N = x?

Comment: I didn't explicitly mention. I implicitly start from a top-level call `(fact N)`, so N becoming the first x value. I wouldn't express it like O(x), as during the recursive execution we encounter a lot of different x values, and so it might be unclear which x value was meant. I'll also edit my answer.

Comment: Since the CL standard does not require TCO you cannot make the assumption that the tail recursive version will be O(1) space. It will be O(N) in some implementations and you need to use the `loop` macro or other looping mechanism to solve this in O(1) space.

Comment: @Sylwester I've been talking about both "decent" and "stupid" compilers, and of course the CL standard doesn't demand tail recursion optimization - that's out of the scope of a language standard. But with CL, chances are good that your compiler does it.

Comment: I would call standard compliant CL "decent". That a specific implementation has TCO is some circumstances (usually when compiled, often not when interpreted) then you could say it's O(1) when compiled in implementation X, but it is still O(N) in Common Lisp since you are not guaranteed TCO and it's not stupid. If someone would make a TCO Python you still cannot say tail calls are optimized. If the standard got TCO requirement you can. A Scheme that doesn't TCO isn't a proper Scheme implementation. When running and blowing the stack it's the users fault for not choosing a standard complient imp